# Accessing usercontrols from the master page in the code behind of aspx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have migrated an application that had no master pages to one using master pages. I removed the references to the user controls from each page and placed them in the master so they could be used in all the pages. In the code behind, I am no longer able to access the properties of each user control. Below is the old code and what I have tried updating it too, but in the new code, get an error trying to access the title property of the user control. Any help would be great!

Old Code:

```
Me.ucNavBar.Title = "Add New Product"
```

New Code:

```
Master.FindControl("ucNavBar").Title = "Add New Product"
```

Error on new code:

```
'Title' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.
```

Comment: Appreciate the heads up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to your specific type to gain access to the Title Property:

```
CType(Master.FindControl("ucNavBar"), UserControl).Title = "Add New Product"
```

Comment: Still gives me the error, 'Title' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.Control'.

Comment: Replace UserControl with the Type of Control you are trying to Cast it to (the one that contains the Title Property).

Answer (score 0):

Would the following help?

Include in .master file:

```
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Navbar" Src="Navbar.ascx" %>
```

and where you need it:

```
    <uc:Navbar runat="server" ID="Navbar" />
```

and access it directly in the master.vb:

```
   Navbar.Title = "Add new product"
```

and to access it in a page that uses the masterpage add the following to .master.vb:

```
   Public Property NavbarTitle as String
   Get
     return Navbar.Title
   Set(ByVal value As String)
     Navbar.Title = value
   End Property
```

.aspx:

```
   <%@ Reference Control="XXXXX.master" %>
```

.aspx.vb

```
    Dim XXXXMaster As XXXXMaster= CType(Me.Page.Master, XXXXMaster)
    CType(XXXXMaster.FindControl("ucNavBar"), UserControl).Title = "Add New Product"
```

or

```
    Dim XXXXMaster As XXXXMaster= CType(Me.Page.Master, XXXXMaster)
    XXXXMaster.NavbarTitle = "Add New Product"
```

FYI, I did not test this code but hope it helps...